# Amazon S3 upload failed - access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to upload files via AWS Amplify to an existing s3 bucket.
**I am not using use AWS MobileHub**.
I created new Identity Pool according to [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRAT5wT8xoE) and in the end this is my policy for this role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my code, I configured Amplify as follows:

```
Amplify.configure({
  'aws_cognito_identity_pool_id': 'us-east-2:f37baa...',
  'aws_cognito_region': 'us-east-2',
  'aws_user_files_s3_bucket': 'demo',
  'aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region': 'us-east-1',
});
```

And I am getting the error:

```
Error: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (s3.js:580)
    at Request.callListeners (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:3610)
    at Request.emit (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:3582)
    at Request.emit (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:7723)
    at Request.transition (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:7062)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:7867)
    at aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:7879
    at Request.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:7078)
    at Request.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:7725)
    at Request.callListeners (aws-sdk-core-react-native.js:3620)
```

**UPDATE**

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
  'aws_cognito_identity_pool_id': 'us-east-2:f37...',
  'aws_cognito_region': 'us-east-2',
  'aws_user_files_s3_bucket': 'demo',
  'aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region': 'us-east-1',
});

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
...
uploadImage = async uri => {
    const fileName = 'example.jpg';
    await Storage.put(fileName, blob, {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      level: 'public'
    }).then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is the whole code, and I just didn't add a file to get but it works for sure.
When I use mobile hub `aws-exports.js`, I can upload the files, but MobileHub creates some bucketsm and my use-case involves using my existing bucket.

Comment: Are you sure this error is about S3 ?  Nothing shows it in the stack trace.  Can you add your code extract to the question ? Also : is the "demo" bucket yours ?  Bucket names are globally unique and I would be surprised you have a bucket named "demo" .  The command "aws s3 ls --region us-east-1" will list your bucket.  My bet here is that you are trying to access a bucket that does not belongs to you.

Comment: I updated question. If I add mobile hub and export config from it it work but it create some additional buckets and I need to add amplify to existing project. No "demo" is just dummy for example it has different name. Where should I type that command?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well, your code is trying to access existing S3 buckets, not the one created by Amplify / Mobile Hub?

If I am correct, you'll need to update the Cognito policies to grant access to your users to the existing S3 Bucket.

In `IAM -> Roles` console, you will find two roles created by Amplify.  Role names are `YOUR_PROJECT____DATE_TAG___[un]authrole`  For example in my console : `photoalbums-20190202155011-unauthRole` and `photoalbums-20190202155011-authRole`

Depending if you want to grant access to authenticated users or unauthenticated users, modify the appropriate role, or both roles if you want both authenticated and unauthenticated user to have access to S3.

Adding the S3 managed policy `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` will grant your user a read only access to your bucket.  (Please do not add `AmazonS3FullAccess` or `s3:*` as it will give your user to create and delete buckets and objects on your account)

Comment: What do you mean by “roles created by amplify”? From amplify I just installed it in my project nothing else

Comment: Amplify is a command line tool to provision cloud resources and a library to use in your front end app to easily access these resources.  Please have a look at the "Getting Started" section of amplify to learn how to use it https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?ref=amplify-js-btn&platform=purejs  If you are trying to use Amplify Libraries with your own backend services, you will need to configure many services manually, leading to potential errors.  If you're using Amplify in your code, it is easier to let it create your cloud resources as well.

Comment: The role you posted at the start of your question seems OK (although way too permissive, entities receiving these permissions will be bale to do *everything* on S3, including changing permission and deleting stuffs, this is probably not what you meant).  What entity is this role attached to ?  How do you attach this role to your code / users ? I guess you're using Cognito User Pool to authenticate your users.  How cognito users receive the permsision you listed ?

Comment: I thought it will be easier to use amplify to plug it and upload files. I will keep using presigned url. I think it’s better there are too much configurations around this